# PHP SQL Query Length

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The following PHP code is from a website I'm trying to make. Basically, I'm trying to dump the contents of a SQL query into rows with 4 columns in each row.

```
<?php
    $prep_stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM eggs WHERE `egg_dist` = 5");
    $prep_stmt->execute();
    $res = $prep_stmt->fetchAll();

    //$row as $r
    for($x = 0; $x < len($res); $x+=4) {
        echo "<div class ='row'>";
        for($y = $x; $y < $x+4; $y++){
            echo "<div class = 'col-3 text-center'>".$res[$y]['name']."</div>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

The outer for loop should execute 1/4 of the length of the resulting query. The inner loop I want to iterate over 4 of the entries from the query array. I was thinking of doing this with a foreach loop, but the problem is at the beginning of the foreach it will start over again, so I have no way of preserving location and hence I am forced to do it with a regular for loop.

My issue is with `len($res)`, which apparently doesn't exist in PHP. I want to get the array length of the fetched prepared statement but don't quite understand how. The php official documentation shows using fetchColumn(), but the way I tried it must have been wrong. I also saw a site that recommended using len(), and clearly that didn't work either, as if it did I wouldn't be making this post.

Comment: [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/function.count.php)

Answer (score 3):

You can get no. of rows return like

```
$count = $prep_stmt->rowCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for no of rows..

/* Number of rows.*/

```
 $stmt->execute();
 $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $count = $data['count(*)'];
```

/*Number of rows*/

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/manual/class.pdostatement.php) does not have a `num_rows` property

Comment: num_rows is there. can you cross check @Phil

Comment: OP is using PDO, not MySQLi

Answer (score -1):

```
$prep_stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM eggs WHERE `egg_dist` = 5 limit 4");
$len = $prep_stmt->num_rows;
while($row = $prep_stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<div class ='row'>";
    $col = array_keys($row);
    for($y = 0; $y < 4; $y++){
        echo "<div class = 'col-3 text-center'>".$row[$col[$y]]."</div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

---

OR if want print only name

```
while($row = $prep_stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<div class ='row'>";
    echo "<div class = 'col-3 text-center'>".$row['name']."</div>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/manual/class.pdostatement.php) does not have a `num_rows` property. Nor does it have a `fetch_assoc()` method